# how can i get the sessionid from a xamarin webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin portable app where i created a page containing a webview. 
I would like to get the sessionId, the server sets the session id in a cookie.

```
class WebViewPage : ContentPage
{
  public WebViewPage()
  {
    var browser = new WebView
    {
        Source = "http://myurl.com"
    };

    browser.Navigated += (sender, args) =>
    {
        ?....someMagic to get the sessionId....?
    };
    Content = browser;
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on your website. How is your SessionId transfered? Cookie, Get-Param, etc.

Comment: my session id is transfered in a cookie